# Android Webview URLStreamHandlerFactory

Tags: java, android, webview, network-programming

I am wanting to do some customization with the WebView for it to use the  OKHttpClient as the URL connection handler. It does have the ability to set itself as a URLStreamHandler by

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(okHttpClient);
```

I can't seem to get it to work though when launching the web view?

Link to OKHttpClient

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.java